# How to set root directory of ftp-srv in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ftp-server

I'm trying to create an ftp server using [ftp-srv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-srv)

Here is my code:

```
const FtpSvr = require ( 'ftp-srv' );

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 5053

const ftpServer = new FtpSvr ({
    url:'ftp://' + hostname + ':' + port ,
    anonymous: false,
    greeting : [ "Hello user"]
});


ftpServer.on('login', (data, resolve, reject) => {
    if(data.username === "user1" && data.password === "ip1") {
        // call resolve
        return resolve({root: '/home/test1/'});
    }
    else{
        // if password and username are incorrectly then call reject
        reject({});
    }
});



ftpServer.listen()
    .then(() =>
    {
        console.log ( `Server Running at ftp://${hostname}:${port}/` );
    });
```

I have set the '/home/test1/' as root directory and the 'test1' permissions is set to 777, but on client side, it raise an error

> an error occurred opening that folder on the ftp server make sure you have permission

Also I tried another ftp client (winscp) and it raised this error:

> Could not retrieve directory listing. Command not supported

I'm really confused!

Comment: I tried it out and I can connect why do you use 0.0.0.0 as ip-address?

Comment: Because I'm not testing it locally. my script is uploaded on a centos 7 server. and I'm trying to connect to it via my pc

Comment: and the connection works fine?

Comment: Yes. it seems its ok

Comment: ok, weird I've tested it locally and it worked fine

Comment: I tried another ftp-client. here is new error message: Could not retrieve directory listing
Command not supported

Comment: Have you tried it locally? I think you code works fine you have to check if there is a problem with the permissions on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the correct options of ftp-srv. And its working now:

```
const FtpSvr = require ( 'ftp-srv' );

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 5053

const ftpServer = new FtpSvr ({
    url:'ftp://' + hostname + ':' + port ,
    pasv_url:'ftp://172.18.56.71' ,
    pasv_min:5054,
    pasv_max:5055,
    file_format: "ls",
    anonymous: false,
    greeting : [ "Hello user"]
});


ftpServer.on('login', (data, resolve, reject) => {
    if(data.username === "user1" && data.password === "ip1") {
        // call resolve
        return resolve({root: './test/'});
    }
    else{
        // if password and username are incorrectly then call reject
        reject({});
    }
});



ftpServer.listen()
    .then(() =>
    {
        console.log ( `Server Running at ftp://${hostname}:${port}/` );
    });
```